# (C++) Storing a pointer to a function with return type deducable at compile time

Tags: c++, pointers, embedded, function-pointers

I have a C++ class that simply stores a `std::string` function pointer passed in via its constructor, executes it when a `getData()` is called, and returns the string. This means I can create an array of pointers to instances of the class for various uses.

I would like to be able to pass the constructor *any* function pointer type, and have `getData()` return a `std::string`. Passing in the function pointer works fine for a function whose return type has an explicit constructor and member variable of the same type as the function in the class; but this means I need a pointer placeholder variable for every possible type.

I considered a templated constructor but then can't store the function pointer as there is no variable with the function's type to store it in - and you can't template member variables. I could template the entire class, but it seems a bit like overkill and calling the constructor involves `className<type>` all over the palace, plus I can't then store the resulting pointer in an array since template types must match.

Also, the constructor is overloaded such that any non-functor type can be passed in too and it is just treated as static data when `getData()` runs.

The code is running on an ESP32, so I'd rather avoid wrapping things in `std::function` to minimise overhead.

A little background: The class forms a very basic interface for other classes to comply to. It is part of a web server which searches for placeholders in HTML files, matches them with the placeholder "registered" as a key in a map, and ultimately runs the value object's `getData()` function. The result of that replaces the placeholder.

The implementation below works as long as the passed in function returns a `std::string()`. It is missing the overloads for non-function types for brevity.

Thanks for any help!

webDataProvider.hpp:

```
#include <string>

#ifndef WEBDATAPROVIDER_HPP
#define WEBDATAPROVIDER_HPP

class webDataProvider
{

private:
    std::string(*funcPtr)() = NULL;

public:
    webDataProvider(){};

    template <class F>
    webDataProvider(F _funcPtr())
    {
        funcPtr = _funcPtr;
    };

    virtual std::string getData()
    {
        return funcPtr();
    }
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "webDataProvider.hpp"

map<std::string, webDataProvider*> globalPlaceholders;


std::string uptime(){
    return std::to_string(esp_timer_get_time());
}

void app_main(){

    globalPlaceholders.emplace("{{uptime}}", new webDataProvider(uptime));

    printf("Placeholder for uptime is %s", globalPlaceholders["{{uptime}}"]->getData().c_str());

}
```

EDIT:
I would like to be able to do this:

main.cpp

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include "webDataProvider.hpp"

map<std::string, webDataProvider*> globalPlaceholders;


std::string uptime(){
    return std::to_string(esp_timer_get_time());
}

float floatValue(){
    //const value purely for example, this could return a different value each time it runs
    return 678.910;
}

void app_main(){
    //example of a function that uses a wrapper
    globalPlaceholders.emplace("{{uptime}}", new webDataProvider(uptime));

    //but it would be cleaner to do this:
    globalPlaceholders.emplace("{{uptime}}", new webDataProvider(esp_timer_get_time));

    globalPlaceholders.emplace("{{float}}", new webDataProvider(floatValue));
}
```

Obviously in this example the integerValue() could return a string, and I could create a stub wrapper function to convert the return type of any functions I use to a string, but that seems rather messy.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. C++ is strongly typed. The type of every object is resolved at compilation time.

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely correct, because runtime type information exists and wouldn't be required if every type was resolved at compilation time? Though I realise that doesn't necessarily mean it is possible to store an unknown type.

Comment: Since beside the return type, which is fixed as `std::string` as you say, only the parameter list can vary, how would you call the function inside of `getdata()` correctly?

Comment: You want to avoid the standard library that does exactly what you want. Does that not sound weird to you?

Comment: @thebusybee I was hoping something like `return std::string(funcPtr());`. It's possible to use auto for function pointers where the type may not be known, but it is not possible to then store that variable outside the scope of the function because the compiler cannot deduce what may end up in that variable. I can pass in a function pointer with any return type to a function with signature `auto regFunc(auto _funcPtr ()) -> std::string{}`, which I can then execute. Just can't think of a way of storing the reference to the the called function to access it later.

Comment: @PasserBy In the context of constrained memory and flash, the `<function>` library is apparently quite heavy, which makes my reasoning less weird I would hope.

Comment: No, you are essentially holding the position that the standard library has an awful implementation, without apparent reason. Have you *measured* `std::function`? What evidence do you have that `std::function` is unsuitable?

Comment: As it does not matter *where* the conversion of any type into a string takes place, why don't you use a wrapper for each (different) type of function, and keep the single declaration of the function pointer? -- You might like to consider to [edit] your question and add some simple examples of different function types.

Comment: @PasserBy I apologise if my statement reads like I assume `<functional>` has an awful implementation. That wasn't the implication I was going for. I have read a number of posts on SO and otherwise stating that it adds a fair bit of overhead to function calls. I have not measured it myself. If it is the only reasonable way of dealing with this then `<functional>` it is!

Comment: @thebusybee I could do that and indeed it seems that may be the only way without using `<functional>`. Avoiding that was really just to keep the code tidy rather than having a batch of wrappers. I have edited the question with a couple of examples of what I'd like to do.

Comment: No apologies are needed, I'm just saying you don't have a compelling reason not to use `std::function`.